# Odd square as sum of $9$ distinct odd squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I'm interested in representing odd squares as sum of $9$ distinct odd squares.

So, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be odd and $x_1,\,x_2,\,...,\,x_9\in\mathbb{N}$ be odd and pairwise distinct. The question is, for which $n$ exists a solution for $$n^2=\sum_{j=1}^9x_j^2$$
I checked the possibilites up to $n=5555$ and in that range, for all $n\geq37$ a solution exists.

Furthermore, in that range besides $n=43$ we can even find solutions of the following more specific form with $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3\geq 13$: $$n^2=1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+9^2+11^2+\sum_{j=1}^3x_j^2\Longleftrightarrow n^2-286=\sum_{j=1}^3x_j^2$$
Solutions for $5555\geq n\geq 37$ can be found here: https://pastebin.com/raw/6B4MBaiw

However, that is obviously not a proof, and I'm wondering, whether it can be proven, that for all $n\geq 37$ at least one solution exists, and maybe even that for $n\geq 37$ with $n\neq 43$ the second equation has at least one solution?

If we don't need our odd squares to be distinct, the problem gets easy.
(Or maybe it's still easy even with distinct odd squares and I just don't see it?)

We use a slight variation of the second equation.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be odd and $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3\in\mathbb{N}$ be odd.

It is $$n^2-6\equiv 3 \mod 8$$
and thus [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) guarantees with $n\geq3$ a solution for $$n^2-6=\sum_{j=1}^3x_j^2\Longleftrightarrow n^2=1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+\sum_{j=1}^3x_j^2$$

Note, that the theorem by itself does not guarantee $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3$ to be odd, but you can only get to the form $8k+3$ with $3$ odd squares.

Comment: OK, try this: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf

Comment: Also, Bohman, J.; Fröberg, C.-E.; and Riesel, H. ``Partitions in Squares.'' BIT 19, 297-301, 1979 may be relevant.

Comment: That paper is here: https://oeis.org/A001156/a001156.pdf

Comment: Why 9 squares: An odd square is 8k+1. To add up to an odd square, you need 1, 9, 17, 25 etc odd squares.

Comment: Related. Let $A$ be an Apollonian gasket generated by the quadruple $(k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4)$. The curvatures of the circles that form the gasket satisfy Descartes Theorem:

$$
(k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4)^2 = 2(k_1^2 + k_2^2 + k_3^2 + k_4^2)
$$ 

So, representing a square as sum of 8 non-distinct squares follows.

Comment: Have you looked at the links I posted, summing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have, but I'm afraid that kind of mathematics is way above my head ;) I get what it's overall about, but following the papers in detail is out of reach for me. However, I saved them, and will read them more thorough when I have the time for it, and maybe get something meaningful out of it for myself.

Comment: That's how Number Theory goes, I'm afraid – elementary-looking problems can lead quickly to deep waters. I wish you good luck. But the next time someone tries to help you, maybe acknowledge the effort without having to be bugged about it, OK?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Regarding: "Without having to be bugged about it" - I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you're saying. Do you mean that I should have written a comment, acknowledging that I read your suggested links? I voted your comments up instead of writing something, because I thought that is how you do things on MSE. It seems like comments are considered spam or off-topic really quick, thus I decided against writing one just to say "thank you". Even under this question, a lot of comments have already been removed, and the one I'm writing right now, will probably also get deleted?

Comment: Not thanks, just an acknowledgement, is what I think is right and proper. Remember, I have no way of knowing who it was that voted my comments up.

Comment: A related, though distinct, question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3466870/ .

Answer (score 5):

I tried to verify this by computer for n larger than 5555. My first attempt - adding nine odd squares and checking whether the sum is again an odd square - didn't work very well. I verified that every odd squares up to $1,000,000^2$ is the sum of nine distinct odd squares, and each solution started with $1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + 7^2 + 9^2 + 11^2$, so only three squares needed to be varied, and the 7th square was always less than $91^2$. The reason this search takes very long is that most of the sums are not squares. That search could have been improved a bit, but not to much.

To verify this for much larger n: Let t be a triangular number (0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 etc.) then $8 \cdot t + 1$ is an odd square (1, 9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169 etc.). So if s is the sum of eight triangular numbers, then $8 \cdot s + 8$ is the sum of eight odd squares.

$(2 \cdot s + 3)^2 - (2 \cdot s + 1)^2 = 8 \cdot s + 8$, so $(8 \cdot s + 8) + (2 \cdot s + 1)^2 = (2 \cdot s + 3)^2$; the left hand side is the sum of nine odd squares, and the right hand side is one odd square.

I verified by computer that every integer from 146 to 62,499,499,999 is the sum of 8 distinct triangular numbers, and therefore every odd square from 295 to $125,000,000,001^2$ is the product of nine odd primes.

But this search found solutions starting with 0 + 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 for all $s \ge 531$. So all integers from 511 to 62,499,999,979 are the sum of three distinct triangular numbers. We can add a fourth triangular number until the distance between two triangular numbers exceeds n = 62,499,999,979, which is at $n \cdot (n + 1)/2 \approx 1.95 \cdot 10^{21}$. We can add a fifth triangular number until the difference between two triangular numbers exceeds $1.95 \cdot 10^{21}$ at $1.9 \cdot 10^{42}$ and so on; each number up to about $1.37 \cdot 10^{336}$ is the sum of 8 triangular numbers.

Therefore every odd square $n^2$ for $n \le 2.74 \cdot 10^{336}$ is the sum of nine odd squares.

Comment: This is certainly a good start and a promising approach. One of the alternatives that occurred to me was to look more generally at the set of numbers  that can be written as a sum of 9 distinct odd squares, ignoring the requirement that the sum should also be a square. With a bit of luck we could cover more ground than what was asked! Your search for sums of triangular numbers is in the same direction, I think.

Comment: @Jyrki, have you looked at the links I gave when the question was first posted?

Comment: Just checked it out @Gerry. Not sure how much the methods say about this variant? Surely we can cook up a suitable generating function. I was a bit surprised about the authors mentioning the result about integers $>128$ being sums of distinct squares. Their proof method seemed to be the same attributed Sprague (from late 1940s IIRC) in Joe Roberts's book, but that reference was not listed at all.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some large-$n$ results from order-of-magnitude arguments.

> **Theorem 1.** There is an ineffective constant $N_3$ such that all $n\geq N_3$ with $n\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ satisfy
> $n=a^2+b^2+c^2$ for some distinct odd integers $a,b,c>11.$
>
> **Theorem 2.** There is an effective constant $N_4$ such that all $n\geq N_4$ with $n\equiv 4\pmod{8}$ satisfy
> $n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ for some distinct odd integers $a,b,c,d>9.$

"Effective" means that in principle you could work out a value by going through
all required proofs and replacing all "there exists $c$..." by explicit values.
Non-effective constants come from non-constructive arguments, in this case by results affected by Siegel zeroes. Unfortunately ineffective constants aren't directly useful.

For $k\in\{2,3,4\},$ define $r_k(n)$ to be the number of tuples $a\in\mathbb Z^k$ such that $n=\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2.$
Define $r_2'(n)$ to be the number of pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$ such that $a^2+2b^2=n.$
Denote the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) by $d(n).$

> **Lemma 3.**
>
> (a) $r_2(n)\leq 4d(n)$
>
> (b) $r_2'(n)\leq 2d(n)$
>
> (c) $d(n)=n^{o(1)}$
>
> (d) $r_3(n)\geq n^{1/2+o(1)}$ for $n\equiv 3\pmod{8},$ but the implicit constants are ineffective
>
> (e) $r_4(n)=8\sum_{m|n\\4\not|m}m$

(a) follows from "Jacobi's two-square theorem", see [Wikipedia's article, "k=2" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sum_of_squares_function&oldid=1164944842#k_=_2).

(b) can be shown by a similar argument as (a), using prime factorization in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ instead of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}].$ The factor of $2$ comes from the fact that there are only two units instead of four.

For (c) see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Divisor_function&oldid=1194303596#Growth_rate).

(d) needs a bit of work to deal with the fact that $n$ might not be square free. let $n=m^2 N$ with $N$ square-free. Then Hirschhorn and Sellers ["On representations of a number as a sum of three squares"](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(98)00288-X) equation (3) implies $r_3(n)\geq r_3(N) m$ - the factor for each prime $p$ in their equation (3) is $\geq p^{\lambda_p}$ where $p^{\lambda_p}$ is the biggest power of $p$ dividing $m.$ And in our case all prime factors are odd. We can then apply the equation $r_3(N)=24h(-N),$ on [Wikipedia's article, "k=3" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sum_of_squares_function&oldid=1164944842#k_=_3) where $h(-N)$ is the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-N}).$ The estimate $h(-N)=N^{1/2+o(1)}$ is given by the [Brauer–Siegel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Siegel_theorem). This gives $r_3(n)/n^{1/2}\geq N^{o(1)}$ where the $o(1)$ tends to zero as $N\to \infty.$ That's also $n^{o(1)}$ as $n\to\infty.$

(e) is "Jacobi's four-square theorem", see [Wikipedia's article, "k=4" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sum_of_squares_function&oldid=1164944842#k_=_4).$\square$

**Proof of Theorem 1.**

By Lemma 3(a,b,c,d), for sufficiently large $n$ we have $r_3(8n+3) > 6\sum_{m\in\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}}r_2(8n+3-m^2) + 6r_2'(8n+3).$ So there is some representation $8n+3=a^2+b^2+c^2$ even after excluding representations with $\{a,b,c\}\cap\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}\neq\emptyset$ or $a=b$ or $b=c$ or $a=c.$
(The factors of $6$ comes from having three options $a,b,c,$ plus an extra choice of sign.)
The condition $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ forces $a,b,c$ to be odd.

**Proof of Theorem 2.**

For any representation $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=n$ with $n\equiv 4\pmod{8},$ we either have $a,b,c,d$ all even, or $a,b,c,d$ all odd. Write $r_4(n)=r^{\mathrm{even}}_4(n)+r^{\mathrm{odd}}_4(n)$
where the first term is the number of representations with $a,b,c,d,$ even,
and the second term is the number with $a,b,c,d$ odd.
By dividing each of $a,b,c,d$ by two we have $r^{\mathrm{even}}_4(n)=r_4(n/4).$
Lemma 3(e) implies $r_4(n)=3r_4(n/4).$
Note $r_4(n/4)\geq n/4.$
Therefore $r^{\mathrm{odd}}_4(n)$ is at least $n/2.$

By considering the "$a$" term of a representation $a^2+b^2+c^2=n$ we have $r_3(n)=\sum_{a^2 \leq n}r_2(n-a^2)$ (with $a$ allowed to be negative). Combining this with Lemma 3(a,c) gives $r_3(n)\leq n^{1/2+o(1)}.$
So there are $\leq n^{1/2+o(1)}$ representations $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=n$ with $\min\{a,b,c,d\}\leq 9.$

Using Lemma 3(a,c) again, there are at most $6\sum_{2m^2\leq n}r_2(n-2m^2)\leq n^{1/2+o(1)}$ representations $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=n$ with $a,b,c,d$ not all distinct. Here $m$ is allowed to be negative. The factor of $6$ comes from the six choices of a two element subset of four.

For sufficiently large $n\equiv 4\pmod 8,$ the quantity $n/2$ is larger than the sum of these $n^{1/2+o(1)}$ terms. Since $r^{\mathrm{odd}}_4(n)\geq n/2,$ there is a representation $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=n$ with $a,b,c,d$ distinct and odd and greater than $9.$

Comment: So if I got it right, you have shown that there exists an unknown constant such that the any integer $\equiv1\pmod8$ above that constant can be written as a sum of nine distinct odd squares?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: yes, by the second equation (“more specific form”) in the question

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *This is not a complete answer, but a result that may be used to progress.*

There is a result of Oliverio [1] generalizing Pythagorean triples to multiple dimensions.

Let $S=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{n-2})$, where $a_i$ are integers, and let $T$ be the number of odd integers in $S$. Then iff $T≢2 \pmod{4}$, there exist integers $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ such that

$$
 a_1^2+a_2^2+ \cdots +a_{n-1}^2=a_n^2 \tag{1}
$$

The OP asks (reframed using the notation used here):

> For $n=10$, which $a_{n}$ does Eqn. $(1)$ have a solution in integers $a_1, a_2 \cdots a_{9}$, all odd and pairwise distinct?

If we choose odd integers $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_8$, with the added condition required by the OP that they be pairwise distinct, then we have $$T = 8 (\equiv 0 \pmod{4} ≢ 2 \pmod{4}).$$

Therefore, by Oliverio's result, there exist integers $a_{9}, a_{10}$ satisfying the equation

$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_8^2 =a_{10}^2 - a_{9}^2 \tag{2}$$

$a_9, a_{10}$ can be found by factoring the LHS in the Eqn. $(2)$.

The added condition is that $a_9$ is odd.

The LHS is the eight squares representation from [Degen's Eight-Square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen%27s_eight-square_identity).

Therefore, for reversing the process, if we have an integer of the form $A \cdot B$, with $A = a_{10} - a_9$ and $B = a_{10} + a_9$ and $a_9$ odd, then we can find 8-square representations of $A, B$ and use that to get $a_1, a_2 \cdots a_{8}$ such that they are odd.

May be suitable for a computer procedure.

**References:**

[1]: Oliverio, P. "Self-Generating Pythagorean Quadruples and N-tuples." Fib. Quart. 34, 98-101, 1996. URL: https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-2/oliverio.pdf

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the question.  Is this intended to answer the question?  If so can you [edit] your answer to explain how it answers the question?  As a reminder, the question asks whether it can be proven that a solution exists for all $n\ge 37$.  Presumably, an answer should either be "Yes" with a proof, or "No" with evidence for that answer.  (Incidentally, I wonder if you noticed that the question specified that the integers must be pairwise distinct.  I don't see how your post has any bearing on the question given the distinctness condition.)